# Download error for php data using wget

Tags: php, wget

I am trying to download data from my server using wget.

I send the login details and store the cookie. I then rotate through 50 numbers to copy the data into new files. The saved files are always blank i.e 0kb file size.

My website stores data on individual pages e.g.: (i have changed my actual site name to "mywebsite")

'http://admin.mywebsite.com/index.php/print_view/?html=true&order_id=50

I am trying to rotate through the numbers 50 to 1 and extract the data from each page.

The code I am using is below:

```
#!/usr/bin/perl

system ("wget --post-data 'username=ghssld&password=ewui394&autologin=1' --cookies=on --keep-session-cookies --save-cookies=cookie.txt 'http://admin.mywebsite.com/index.php/login");

$x = 50;
while ($x <= 1) {
system ("wget --wait=400 --post-data 'html=true&order_id=50' --referer=http://admin.mywebsite.com/ --cookies=on --load-cookies=cookie.txt --keep-session-cookies --save-cookies=cookie.txt 'http://admin.mywebsite.com/index.php/print_view/");

system ("wget --post-data 'html=true&order_id=50' --referer=http://admin.mywebsite.com/ --cookies=on --load-cookies=cookie.txt --keep-session-cookies --save-cookies=cookie.txt 'http://admin.mywebsite.com/index.php/print_view?");
$x++;
}
```

Can anyone help me modify my code so data is pulled correctly and the saved files are not blank? (I have commented the hyperlink addresses because I'm a new user and I can only post one hyperlink!)
Thank you

Comment: I just realized this should probably on SO not SF.

Answer (score 0):

First off, the code you posted is using a Perl interpreter which makes 0 sense. The code does look like PHP so the tags are correct.

Second, is there a reason why you need to use wget? I would recommend curl:
http://php.net/manual/en/book.curl.php

If you really need to use wget, this seems like a better job for a simple BASH script.

Otherwise, you need to post more information. I'm not 100% sure, but a tool like wget should spit out error messages if something didn't work correctly.

Comment: Thanks for your advice. I successfully used curl to extract the data i needed. I now need to extract relevant words from a series of the html files by the user. e.g. Name, Address, Mobile and DOB. I would be grateful if you could point me in the right direction so i can write a script that will extract the name, address out of each html file and put the data into a csv/text file for uploading into a spreadsheet.

Comment: That is rather easy with regular expressions, but not a question for serverfault. Post your new code and question on stackoverflow.com.